# SaaS Billing and Multi-tenant starter kit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, saas, starter-kits

I'm just about finished with a solution built with ASP.NET MVC.  Apart from a few bits and pieces, I only have security to do.  I was wondering if there is some sort of starter code somewhere which I can build into my application (or build my current files into) which will do the following:

- Subscription page for tenants (think they are called tenants, see note below), which will assign a administrator to the account.
- A way to invite others to join and work on the tenant's data.
- User groups and roles to limit what each of these other users can see/do.
- Standard Login/forgot password pages
- It doesn't need to handle billing, but if it does, it's an added bonus

My understanding of a tenant here is a person that signs up and then invite others to access their data.  It is also be called vendor sometimes.

I'm sure there must be something out the box, because the above are features of most SaaS apps nowadays.  I'm aware that I will need to add clauses to all existing queries to ensure that tenants don't see each other's data.

Any solutions that anyhow know of?  Please let me know.  Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/saaskit/saaskit